# Upgrading to team in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

My work has just upgraded my personal dropbox account to a 'Team' account, does that make all my current files available to everybody in my team?

Thanks,
Chmouel.

Answer (score 3):

Dropbox team edition simply means that you have additional space/features available to you.

Your account works in the exact same way, but, folders shared between your team simply come out of the team allowance instead of your personal one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest checking out the [Dropbox Team](https://www.dropbox.com/teams) page.

From this support [answer](https://www.dropbox.com/help/211), it *appears* not - but verify with Dropbox :)

> When you upgrade to Teams, you will retain all of your existing folders and files and any shared folders and active public links. You can also use any existing installed Dropbox application, so no new downloads are required.
>
> If you'd prefer to keep your work account separate from a personal account, ask your Teams account administrator to email the invite to the email address under which you will create the new account. Also, you can always change the email address associated to your Dropbox account by going to your Account Settings tab from the Account page

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/help/213) may be helpful, too.